# Как загрузить картинку из интернета в Алерт диалог?

Tags: android

Создал свой Алерт диалог.
Вставил картинки в него, дал id для того что бы потом загрузить картинку с интернета...
В итоге, при открытии Алерт диалога он открылся, а вот когда начался показ картинок, (Приложение вышло из строя!). Не понимаю с чем это связано!
Кто-то может помочь с этим? Обьяснить что я делаю не так.

Код мой такой:

```
public class Plagins300 extends Activity { 
@Override 
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){ 
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState); 
    setContentView(R.layout.plagins); 
}

public void plagin_top1(View v){

    LayoutInflater inflater = getLayoutInflater();
    View dialoglayout = inflater.inflate(R.layout.plagin_top1, null);
    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
    builder.setView(dialoglayout);
    builder.setTitle("Регистрация");     
    builder.show();

    // Показать картинку 1
    new DownloadImageTask((ImageView) findViewById(R.id.plagintop1ImageView1))
        .execute("https://pp.userapi.com/c841131/v841131097/6b127/nXfP-y-HYuk.jpg");
}

public void onClick(View v) {
    startActivity(new Intent(this, Plagins300.class));
    finish();

}

private class DownloadImageTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Bitmap> {
    ImageView bmImage;

    public DownloadImageTask(ImageView bmImage) {
        this.bmImage = bmImage;
    }

    protected Bitmap doInBackground(String... urls) {
        String urldisplay = urls[0];
        Bitmap mIcon11 = null;
        try {
            InputStream in = new java.net.URL(urldisplay).openStream();
            mIcon11 = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(in);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e("Ошибка передачи изображения", e.getMessage());
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return mIcon11;
    }

    protected void onPostExecute(Bitmap result) {
        bmImage.setImageBitmap(result);
    }
}
```

Это вроде бы весь код.

Comment: Во первых, нужны логи ошибки - без них помочь вам невозможно. Во вторых - отображайте картинки библиотеками типа Glide. А так у вас проблема, наверное, в том, что картинка в диалоге, а вы её в разметке активити ищите. Ищите в разметке диалога

Comment: А можете показать, как искать в разметке диалога? А не активити как вы говорите.

Comment: Попробуйте заменить `(ImageView) findViewById(R.id.plagintop1ImageView1)` на `(ImageView) dialoglayout.findViewById(R.id.plagintop1ImageView1)`.

Comment: @post_zeew Огромное спасибо, все работает! Удачи вам)